# Limiting current draw from a power supply

Tags: dc, inductor, high-voltage, current-limiting

I have a power supply that can supply around -60 kV DC and 10 mA. This power supply provides energy to a device known as a fusor. A fusor utilizes a low current and a high voltage to ionize a gas and accelerate the plasma ions toward the center of the vacuum chamber.

However, my issue is that the fusor will pull a very high current (100 mA) for around 30 seconds to ionize the gas. Afterwards, it settles back to 10 mA. Unfortunately, my power supply can only supply up to 10 mA and cannot supply that 100 mA draw during the first few seconds.

To combat this issue, I was considering using an inductor. Would this work? Also, what would the specs of such an inductor be?

Comment: You need to ask yourself if you *need* the fusor to have that 100ma of current.  If you do, you're thinking wrong-- you need a capacitor to store the charge you need (probably a very big one!)

Comment: What is the design of the 60 kV supply? The HV supplies I've worked with if you try to pull too much current, the output voltage just drops without any damage being done (at least for short overloads).

Comment: Greetings, it automatically draws 100 mA, I don't want it to take 100 mA, I want it to take 10 mA. Also, the power supply is a 60 kV 600 W electrostatic precipitator from EBay (CX-600A).

Comment: Will the plasma arc come into being, unless the gas is quickly heated by the 100mA current?

Comment: Think about it like this, there is a small ball at the center of a big spherical vacuum chamber. When I plug my high voltage power supply into the small ball, I am feeding it 60 kV and 10 mA. HOWEVER since it is in a vacuum chamber (with a small amount of gas) the small ball will start to pull a lot more amps, as it want to have the power jump to the vacuum chamber walls. As a result of this, the current draw goes from 10 mA to 100 mA for about 30 seconds. I want to make something to limit the current to 10 mA and stop the spike to 100 mA.

Comment: So, again, what is the design of your supply? Are you sure it isn't self-limiting? Any thing you do that limits the current to the load will have to reduce the voltage delivered to the load to do that. If the supply has that behavior already, you don't need any additional circuit.

Comment: Your power supply doesn't have any load protection (built in)?

Comment: It does, but the current protection would completely kill the power output if the power being pulled is above 10 mA. Thus, I need something like an inductor to decrease the amount of current that is being pulled by the load (the fusor).

Comment: Are you still expecting to get 60kV while limiting the current to 10mA?

Comment: No, I am expecting a significant drop, the 60 kV is all that I need.

Comment: Your comment seems contradictory to me - "No, I am expecting a significant drop, the 60 kV is all that I need."

Answer (score 0):

The physics lab manager wanted to build a CO2 laser. In short, he succeeded; we tested it while wearing special protect-the-eyes goggles. The laser was powered by 2,000 volt 0.1 amp CONSTANT CURRENT supply. Cooling water flowed, removing about 95% of the energy.

He asked my advice for how to control the power(current), and I suggested TRIACS, with pulse transformers to turn on the TRIACS at appropriate timing (phases) of the incoming 60Hz power. Thus his control system, to "regulate" the current, had 120 samples per second "bandwidth".

The laser worked; producing about 10 watts in 1cm*2 beam. Would set the standard lab screen-wire-and-asbestos pads ON FIRE in about 5 seconds.

What size output capacitor was used? I do not recall. But using the maths

dV/dT = I/C, and rearranging to get C = I / (dV/dT) or C = I * dT /dV

we learn, for 10 volts ripple, 1/120 seconds, at 0.1 amp

C = 0.1 amp * 0.00833 seconds / 10 volts

or

C = 80 microFarads, with 5,000 volt rating??

Comment: Greetings, in my case, I am dealing with DC power.

Comment: Then you need a 100,000 volt-rated  triode vacuum tube, as your series current controller. Varian-EIMAC may produce those.